# Swing GUI on Netbeans 8

Tags: swing, netbeans

There seems no way of creating Swing GUI form projects on Netbeans 8.0.2, there is no such choice in new project wizard. But Swing palette is available Tools > Palette > Swing/AWT Components. See the attached screen shots. We used to have Swing GUI builder on earlier Netbeans versions.

Is there a way to have Swing visual GUI builder on Netbeans 8.0.2?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a "plain" Java application, and then you can create GUI components within it.

Create a Java Application as in your screen shot #1 and then create a new file.  You will see a "Swing GUI Forms" category from which you can choose JDialog, JPanel etc.

There is no specific application type for GUI applications, any of the standard Java application types can be used for creating desktop applications.